# Use elasticsearch-hadoop to load elasticsearch array type from Pig

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-pig

I am having problems with writing a string array from Pig to ES (using elasticsearch-hadoop).  The current ES-hadoop documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/pig.html) states that a pig Bag maps to a ES Array, but I am not getting the results I expect.  I am using the elasticsearch-hadoop plugin version 1.3.0.M2 with hadoop 2.0.

Here is the elasticsearch-hadoop documentation that shows the type mapping:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/pig.html#pig-type-conversion

Here is an example:

```
% register elasticsearch-hadoop plugin jar ...
% test_data = A,B,C
data = LOAD 'test_data' USING PigStorage (',') AS (f1: chararray, f2: chararray, f3: chararray);
data2 = FOREACH data GENERATE TOBAG(f1, f2, f3) AS my_fields;
STORE data2 INTO 'dgb-1610/test' USING EsStorage();
...
dump data2
({(A),(B),(C)})
...
describe data2
data2: {my_fields: {(chararray)}}
```

this is what the resulting index looks like:

```
curl -XGET 'http://myhappyserver.com:9200/dgb-1610/test/_mapping'
{
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "my_fields": {
                "properties": {
                    "0": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this is how I expect it to be:

```
{
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "my_fields": {
                "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```